# Timeout when calling $mail->anyparameter with PHPMailer

Tags: php, email, ubuntu, xampp, phpmailer

as subject, I am trying to sending email with PHPMailer. But strangely, examples from PHPMailer only works on XAMPP Windows but not XAMPP Linux. I did not modify complex settings, the settings I changed from XAMPP Linux is only enabling openssl.

I am trying to execute basic code below, it works only for XAMPP Windows but not XAMPP Linux. The script were timeout each time the php process the line contains `$mail->`.

```
 <?php
 require_once "phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php";
 $mail = new PHPMailer;

 //die("ok");
 $mail->AddAddress("email address", "name");
 $mail->SetFrom("email address", "name");
 $mail->WordWrap = 50;
 $mail->IsHTML(true);
 $mail->Subject = "Subject";
 $mail->Body    = "<p>HTML Test</p>";
 $mail->Send()
 ?>
```

Timeout message:

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /opt/lampp/htdocs/phpmailertest/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php on line 767
```

Line 767 of class.phpmailer.php:

```
return (boolean)preg_match('/^(?!(?>(?1)"?(?>\\\[ -~]|[^"])"?(?1)){255,})(?!(?>(?1)"?(?>\\\[ -~]|[^"])"?(?1)){65,}@)((?>(?>(?>((?>(?>(?>\x0D\x0A)?[\t ])+|(?>[\t ]*\x0D\x0A)?[\t ]+)?)(\((?>(?2)(?>[\x01-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\'*-\[\]-\x7F]|\\\[\x00-\x7F]|(?3)))*(?2)\)))+(?2))|(?2))?)([!#-\'*+\/-9=?^-~-]+|"(?>(?2)(?>[\x01-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-!#-\[\]-\x7F]|\\\[\x00-\x7F]))*(?2)")(?>(?1)\.(?1)(?4))*(?1)@(?!(?1)[a-z0-9-]{64,})(?1)(?>([a-z0-9](?>[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)(?>(?1)\.(?!(?1)[a-z0-9-]{64,})(?1)(?5)){0,126}|\[(?:(?>IPv6:(?>([a-f0-9]{1,4})(?>:(?6)){7}|(?!(?:.*[a-f0-9][:\]]){8,})((?6)(?>:(?6)){0,6})?::(?7)?))|(?>(?>IPv6:(?>(?6)(?>:(?6)){5}:|(?!(?:.*[a-f0-9]:){6,})(?8)?::(?>((?6)(?>:(?6)){0,4}):)?))?(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9])(?>\.(?9)){3}))\])(?1)$/isD', $address);
```

Here is my details:

- Ubuntu 12.10 desktop without LAMP component, only XAMPP for Linux
- XAMPP version 1.8.1 (definitely latest version)
- PHPMailer from https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer version master.

Looks like something is wrong with my XAMPP Linux but I cant trace the problem.

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the *exact* same problem. I fixed it with a dirty hack.
Replace the function (Starting with `public static function ValidateAddress($address) {`) with this:

```
public static function ValidateAddress($address) {
    return true;
}
```

This will validate any address you supply, **any**!

You should check addresses yourself before using them with PHPMailer. I don't know what could happen if you don't, just check the addresses.

Comment: Thanks! Anyway, when I am before trying to execute your code, PHPMailer is back to normal, and I did not modify anything :| Its really weird!

Comment: @mokalovesoulmate Glad you were able to solve your problem, if your question is solved you should close this question. :)

Answer (score 0):

Edit your `PHP.ini` file.
this should be in your `PHP` folder.

search for **maximum_execution_time** out in that file.
edit the value - it's in seconds. - - the default should be 30.

eg:-

```
replace maximum_execution_time  30
      with   maximum_execution_time 3000(for 5 minutes if that helps)
```

> **Note from editor**: This does not always work. Please see above for the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and just found out that this isn't related to PHPMailer itself. It has something to do with your SMTP Server. My provider just told me that there were issues. I suggest to contact your administrator first when you have this problem.